# Instagram bot not going to the next image

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have made an Instagram bot about 1 year ago.

From time to time Instagram has changed the code structure but I have always managed to successfully modify it in order to work.

Since a couple of weeks ago, Instagram has changed drastically.

I have made some changes but I will skip the Following part  for the moment.

Currently I am facing some issues on selecting the next image after liking one.

```
for hashtag in hashtag_list:
    tag += 1
    webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'+ hashtag_list[tag] + '/')
    sleep(5)
    first_thumbnail = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div')
    
    first_thumbnail.click()
    sleep(randint(10,15))    
    try:        
        for x in range(1,30):

            # Liking the picture
            like_button = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-label="Like"]')
            like_button.click()

            likes += 1
            sleep(5)

            # Comments and tracker
            comm_prob = randint(1,11)
            print('{}_{}: {}'.format(hashtag, x,comm_prob))
            if comm_prob > 7:
                comments += 1
                #webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[2]/button').click()
                comment_button = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@aria-label="Comment"]')
                comment_button.click()
                comment_box = webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')

                if (comm_prob < 7):
                    comment_box.send_keys('Really cool :D!')
                    sleep(5)
                elif (comm_prob > 6) and (comm_prob < 9):
                    comment_box.send_keys('Interesting work!')
                    sleep(5)
                elif comm_prob == 9:
                    comment_box.send_keys('Nice gallery!')
                    sleep(5)
                elif comm_prob == 10:
                    comment_box.send_keys('Cool view!')
                    sleep(5)
                elif comm_prob == 11:
                    comment_box.send_keys('Wonderful view :)')
                    sleep(5)
                # Enter to post comment
                comment_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
                sleep(3)


                followed += 1
                
                nxt = webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
                nxt.click()
                sleep(2)
            nxt = webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
            nxt.click()
            sleep(2)
        nxt = webdriver.find_element_by_link_text('Next')
        nxt.click()
        sleep(2)


    # some hashtag stops refreshing photos (it may happen sometimes), it continues to the next
    except:
        continue
```

I have managed to make it work again using the above code. Right now it is liking a picture and skipping one. I tried to remove one of the "Next" blocks but it won't go to the next picture anymore...well, better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your logical bug is here:

```
if webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/a').text != 'x':
```

The `/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/a` locator is matching the opened thumbnail user name but you are comparing it with 'x' string.
So since the user name is not equals to 'x', you will always enter this block and will actually like and unlike in endless loop the same, the first user.
Moreover, there is `else` case for the above `if`.
It checks for clicks counter. So since you will always click on the click inside the `if` and just increase the `clicks` counter you will never click with `webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/a').click()` but you will try to perform click with  `webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]').click()`.
However I see this locator is wrong, no such element. So nothing will be clicked, you will stay inside the first opened thumbnail and click on "like" button there endlessly.
Additionally to the above I would recommend you never use the automatically generated locators like those you are using here. they are extremely unreliable. You have yo learn how to make correct locators.

Comment: I have modified the code: so basically now it is searching for the aria label "Like" and if found it should press the Like button. Incrementing the likes counter correctly this time, but it seems my logic isn't so good because now it doesn't even like the first photo

Comment: You still not changed `if webdriver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div/span/a').text != 'x':` as I see

Comment: It is changed, please check the last edited code

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, fixed that

Comment: Thanks. I really have no time now, maybe tomorrow.

Comment: It's not urgent, just want to find a logic that will fix the issue :) thank you for your patience!

Comment: I have managed to make it go to the next picture, I have described all in the main post. thank you!

Comment: Great! I'm sorry I could not help you, really busy these days. have several big and urgent projects to do.

Comment: Your suggestions helped me to get the final result. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm really happy for this :) It's my pleasure.